# Local XML declarations difference

Tags: layout, ee-1.13, local.xml

I need help in better undestanding how the local.xml file works and how can I manage to get a new way of achieving certain functionality within the logged in customer pages.

I want to be able to have content from different blocks/modules on a single page and I've managed to get these blocks to show but I don't understand why, on local.xml inserting the code in one way works and the other doesn't.
Look at the customer_account_index, more specifically the code just bellow `<!-- sales history -->`

This works:

```
    <customer_account_index>
    <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>top</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/min-side.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <!-- Calendar -->
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
            <block type="core/template" name="customer.calendar" as="customer.calendar" template="customer/account/dashboard/customer.calendar.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="customer.calendar.inactive" as="customer.calendar.inactive" template="customer/account/dashboard/customer.calendar.inactive.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="customer.calendar.switch.link" as="customer.calendar.switch.link" template="customer/account/dashboard/customer.calendar.switch.link.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="customer.calendar.inactive.link" as="customer.calendar.inactive.link" template="customer/account/dashboard/customer.calendar.inactive.link.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </reference>

    <!-- sales history -->
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_history" name="sales.order.history">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="sales.order.history.info" as="info" translate="label">
                <label>Order History Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="customer/account/link/back.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <!-- discounts -->
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="core/template" name="customer_your_discounts" template="customer/account/dashboard/discounts.phtml">
            <block type="enterprise_reward/customer_reward_info" name="customer.reward.info.godt" template="reward/customer/reward/info.phtml"/>
            <block type="enterprise_reward/customer_reward_history" name="customer.reward.history.godt" template="reward/customer/reward/history.phtml"/>
            <block type="discounts/discounts" name="customer.price.rules" template="reward/pricerules.phtml"/>
            <block type="discounts/discounts" name="customer.checkout.cart.coupon" template="customer/account/dashboard/coupon.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

But this doesn't:

```
    <customer_account_index>
    <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>top</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/min-side.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <!-- Calendar -->
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
            <block type="core/template" name="customer.calendar" as="customer.calendar" template="customer/account/dashboard/customer.calendar.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="customer.calendar.inactive" as="customer.calendar.inactive" template="customer/account/dashboard/customer.calendar.inactive.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="customer.calendar.switch.link" as="customer.calendar.switch.link" template="customer/account/dashboard/customer.calendar.switch.link.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="customer.calendar.inactive.link" as="customer.calendar.inactive.link" template="customer/account/dashboard/customer.calendar.inactive.link.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </reference>

    <!-- discounts -->
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="core/template" name="customer_your_discounts" template="customer/account/dashboard/discounts.phtml">
            <block type="enterprise_reward/customer_reward_info" name="customer.reward.info.godt" template="reward/customer/reward/info.phtml"/>
            <block type="enterprise_reward/customer_reward_history" name="customer.reward.history.godt" template="reward/customer/reward/history.phtml"/>
            <block type="discounts/discounts" name="customer.price.rules" template="reward/pricerules.phtml"/>
            <block type="discounts/discounts" name="customer.checkout.cart.coupon" template="customer/account/dashboard/coupon.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>

<sales_order_history translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Order History</label>
    <update handle="customer_account_index"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_history" name="sales.order.history">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="sales.order.history.info" as="info" translate="label">
                <label>Order History Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="customer/account/link/back.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</sales_order_history>
```

I just inserted the `<sales_order_history>` (copied from sales.xml) in full and removed the reference from the `<customer_account_index>` but nothing seems to happen even though I don't see any errors.

What's the difference between these two declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, the first code will work and second code will not. I will try to explain the reason in detail.

First of all, the issue is not related to `local.xml`. `local.xml` file is just a layout update xml file which will get considered at last by Magento. So your layout update will definitely going to work since you used `local.xml` file and *blocks which you are referencing* are already available at the time Magento process `local.xml`.

Second thing is, `sales_order_history` is a ***layout update handle***. This layout handle is a special layout handle that will consider by Magento only when you are in `sales/order/history` page. In all other pages, this layout handle will not be used. This is what makes second layout update didn't work at all. You are now in *customer-page* and not in *sales-order-history-page* and due to this, Magento will not process `sales_order_history` layout handle in that case.

The first layout update worked because, you inserted the code inside the layout handle `customer_account_index`. This layout handle will consider by Magento only when you are in *customer-account-page*. Due to this, Magento will insert your `sales/order_history` block inside `my.account.wrapper` block and thus you will see the inserted blocks in customer account page.

So in short, Magento is using layout handles to process layout updation of a page. Some layout handles will be used in every page request (eg: `default`) and some other layout handles will be used in some page requests and at last there are some special layout handles that will be processed only for one page (eg : `catalog_product_view`).So you can insert any number of layout udpate handles in a single layout update xml file (such as `local.xml`). But Magento will consider your inserted blocks according to the layout update handle. So you should insert your blocks inside the proper layout handle. Dumping your blocks in `local.xml` is not going to work. You should put them in proper position, means inside the proper *layout update handle*.

Comment: That actually makes sense and is in line with what I thought was happening. So basically, in order to have everything in a single page, I have to add every single block I intend to use to, say, `customer_account_index` or otherwise they won't be rendered.. Thank you!

Comment: Yes correct.  Please tick my answer if it helped you to clear your doubts